# Terraform: How do I force a resource update after running a null resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

thats my terraform-code:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "file_upload" {
  for_each = fileset("init_conf/", "*")
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.conf_bucket.id
  acl    = "private"
  key    = "config/${local.service_name}/${each.value}"
  source = "init_conf/${each.value}"
  source_hash = filemd5("init_conf/${each.value}")
  kms_key_id = "arn:aws:kms:##################:###################"
  server_side_encryption = "aws:kms"
  

  tags = merge(tomap({
               "Name" = local.service_name,
  }), local.default_tags)
}


resource "null_resource" "cert" {

  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -keyout ${path.cwd}/init_conf/${var.cname}.key -out ${path.cwd}/init_conf/${var.cname}.crt"
  }
}
```

After the execution of terraform apply, the status of the: resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "file_upload" is refreshed first and only then the: provisioner "local-exec" is executed. What I want, however, is that the: provisioner "local-exec" is executed first, which generates a certificate for me and stores it, and only then does the file upload with the: resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "file_upload".

Can someone help ?

Comment: Add a `depends_on` attribute on the `aws_s3_bucket_object`.

Comment: How did it go? Is is still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 1):

You can add:

```
depends_on = [null_resource.cert]
```

to your `aws_s3_bucket_object.file_upload`:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "file_upload" {
  for_each = fileset("init_conf/", "*")
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.conf_bucket.id
  acl    = "private"
  key    = "config/${local.service_name}/${each.value}"
  source = "init_conf/${each.value}"
  source_hash = filemd5("init_conf/${each.value}")
  kms_key_id = "arn:aws:kms:##################:###################"
  server_side_encryption = "aws:kms"
  
  depends_on = [null_resource.cert] 

  tags = merge(tomap({
               "Name" = local.service_name,
  }), local.default_tags)
}
```

Comment: Nice thought, but unfortunately doesn't work. Here is the Terraform output for that:  `module.fargate_deployment.aws_s3_bucket_object.file_upload["nginx.conf"]: Refreshing state... [id=config/backend/nginx.conf]
module.fargate_deployment.aws_s3_bucket_object.file_upload[".gitkeep"]: Refreshing state... [id=config/backend/.gitkeep]`

Comment: @RELiABLE I don't see any errors. Seems fine to me.

Comment: And after that: `module.fargate_deployment.null_resource.cert: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
module.fargate_deployment.null_resource.cert (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "openssl req -new -newkey rsa.....................`

Comment: @RELiABLE You must have used my answer incorrectly, or your question is not representative of your real code.

Comment: The certificate is built at the end and then no longer uploaded.

Comment: @RELiABLE `depends_on = [null_resource.cert]` forces correct order.

Comment: According to you, I did it that way, but the order does not change. `resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "file_upload" {
  for_each = fileset("init_conf/", "*")
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.conf_bucket.id
  acl    = "private"
  key    = "config/${local.service_name}/${each.value}"
  source = "init_conf/${each.value}"
  source_hash = filemd5("init_conf/${each.value}")
  kms_key_id = "arn:aws:kms:#########"
  server_side_encryption = "aws:kms"
  depends_on  = [null_resource.cert]
}
`

Comment: @RELiABLE What is your TF version?

Comment: `Terraform has been successfully initialized!
main.tf
Success! The configuration is valid.
Terraform v1.0.11
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.68.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null v3.1.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template v2.2.0`

Comment: @RELiABLE Can you update the question with the actual full execution log? You only showed `Refreshing state`. There is no log showing actual execution of the code.

Comment: @RELiABLE How did it go? Did you find the full execution log?

Comment: Many thanks for your effort. In the meantime I've found another way.